# Preview is not showing after upload

Tags: 7, views, theming, media, files

When i am trying to upload image as a Authenticate user, After upload i am not able to see preview. fields got disappear fully.

If i try to do as a admin, i am able to see that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: please copy-paste your permissions (fields, node & files) as an image

Comment: its 775.  all permissions are fine

Comment: you are providing very little info, have you field permission module? do you have some custom module affecting permissions? as admin you have all rigths to see/update everything, to me it looks that you have a permissions issue.

Comment: I am facing issue if i am editing other fields with image. or alone image. Other fields are working fine, if i dont touch image

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you have private file setting turned on and have not given permission to authenticated users to see an uploaded field.

But the commenters above are correct, there are literally a dozen or more ways a field may not display an image. A few that come to mind:

- Images styles aren't writeable
- A preprocess function has a weird permission it's checking
- .htaccess or server settings is screwing up the image headers
- the path is getting rewritten because of a path alias
- Some access module is being wonky
- The access permissions are out of date and need to be flushed
- You have a field-level access module preventing authenticated users from seeing the image field
- You are using some display module that is tweaking your template or display mode based on permissions
- The views module is tweaking your field availability
- etc